# How to find if a string contains any items of an List of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, collections

I have a string and a List of strings:

```
string motherString = "John Jake Timmy Martha Stewart";
```

and I want to find if that string contains any of the strings in a list ie:

```
var children = new List<string>{"John", "Mike", "Frank"};
```

So I want to find out if motherString contains one of the items from children ie. 'John'

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: Will all the words in the mother string be seperated by spaces? If there was a child item "John" and motherString contained "Johnathan", would you want to return success?

Comment: No, I want exact matches

Comment: Check the updated solution :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest code I could come up with would be:

```
var hasAny = children.Any(motherString.Contains);
```

If you expect each of the words to be seperated by a space then you could use this:

```
var hasAny = motherString.Split(new[] { ' ' }).Any(children.Contains);
```

If the words in motherString could be seperated by other characters, you could add them like this:

```
motherString.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', ':' })
```

Comment: Almost 4 years later and still a great & simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: To ignore case var hasAny = children.Any(c => motherString.Contains(c, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));