# OR Operand in C# for Strings

Tags: c#, string, operands

Is there no OR operand in C# for strings?

I'm looking at the Microsoft C# operands page - and nothing on any sort of OR for strings.

I've got an if statement I am trying to write:

```
if (Convert.ToString(r["first_name"]) != "Antoine" || "Brad" || "Programming" || "Admin" || "Patricia")
                                   {
```

which C# is choking on with this error:

```
CS0019: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'
```

I am used to Python and PHP, where doing something similar to this is allowed.

What is the proper syntax for C#?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987873/how-to-find-if-a-string-contains-any-items-of-an-list-of-strings will help

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Operators aren't designed for types but for boolean expressions.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Well, that's true of the boolean operators anyway.

Answer (score 12):

You could make it a collection, then use contains

```
if (!(new []{"Antoine", "Brad", "Programming", "Admin", "Patricia"}.Contains(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"])))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that.

Instead, you can write

```
if (someString != "a" && someString != "b" && ...)
```

Comment: `You can't do that.` -- Oppressor!

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((r["first_name"]) != "Antoine" || (r["first_name"]) != "Brad" || (r["first_name"]) !="Programming" || (r["first_name"]) != "Admin" ||r(["first_name"]) != "Patricia")
```

Comment: That will give a compiler warning.

Comment: You're re comparing `object` to `string`; that won't call the overloaded `==`.

Comment: I did this. It gave me no warning.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the code, declare the values you want to check against.

```
var badNames = new HashSet<string> {"Antoine", "Brad", "Programming", "Admin", "Patricia"};
```

Then later when you need to see if that string is in the collection.

```
if(!badNames.Contains(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"]))){
    return "Its all good.";
}
```

As an added bonus the `HashSet` constructor can take a comparer that will let you do case insensitive compares.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can put those strings in an Array and verify if contains the r["first_name"]:

```
        var names = new[]{ "Antoine", "Brad", "Programming", "Admin", "Patricia" };

        if (names.Contains(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"])))
        {
            //doSomething
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the strings you want to OR into an array and then check to see if the array contains the first name.

So:

```
var names = new [] {"Antoine", "Brad", "Programming", "Admin", "Patricia"};
```

Then:

```
var match = names.Contains(r["first_name"]);
```