# Predicate filtration of collection in c# with LINQ and necessity to compare results with List<string> elements

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I am  filtering in C# with LINQ my collection  according to below given code. It is working for my purpose at first good. But I have a situation that in the filtering I have to compare one of the fields of my object (ProductNo) with values from List. As long as I know how many elements will have this table I can do this. But I want to extend functionality so that my code will automatically check how many  times should check this statement:

```
((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(foundPT[i])
```

Please help me I was looking for solutions and the closest solution which I found was this one:

[How to find if a string contains any items of an List of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987873/how-to-find-if-a-string-contains-any-items-of-an-list-of-strings)

But I cannot implement it in my case.

```
static public ICollectionView ProductionTravelersFilter(ObservableCollection<ProductList> obProductList, string searchedString)
{
            // Collection which will take ObservableCollection
            var _itemSourceList = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = obProductList };
            // ICollectionView the View/UI part 
            ICollectionView Itemlist = _itemSourceList.View; 
            List<string> foundPT = FilteredProductionTravelers(searchedString);
            int arrayLength=foundPT.Count;
            // your Filter
            var CustomFilter = new Predicate<object>(item =>
                                    ((ProductList)item).TakenFromProductNo.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).DrawingNumber.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).ProductType.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).Material.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).CreationDate.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).Application.Contains(searchedString) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).Description.Contains(searchedString)||
                                    ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(foundPT[0]) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(foundPT[1]) ||
                                    ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(foundPT[2]) ||
                                    );
    
            //add our Filter
            Itemlist.Filter = CustomFilter;
            return Itemlist;
}
```

Comment: You can use Any: ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Any(a=>foundPT.Contains(a))

Comment: Hi Niki, with your solution I am getting following error message: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: Previously when I used simillar syntax: ((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Any(foundPT.Contains) I got similar error message: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<char, bool>'

Comment: I assumed property ProductNO is collection of some kind. If it is string, you can use foundPT.Any(a=>((ProductList)item).ProductNo.Contains(a))